# Display an image on button click

Tags: java, image, swing, jbutton

I'm trying to code a `JButton` in Netbeans and I want to display an image from my local disk when the button is clicked.  This button is inside a panel.

How to display an image when I click a button?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)   Where are you stuck?

Comment: Add a `JLabel` to a `JFrame`.  Set the image to the `JLabel`, show the frame. You might like to have read through [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html)

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13512826/418556) for a GUI that can display images, and [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13521592/418556) for a file chooser suited to selecting images.  Pop the file chooser on action event, then show the image(s) in the GUI.

Comment: Sorry my question was not clear in fact i want to display an image from my local disk in a Message dialog, so this is what i tried  private void jButtonHelpActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
final ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("D:\\folder\\help.png");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, icon);

Comment: 1) Edit code into questions and use code formatting.  It is almost unreadable in comments.  2) The only new information (short of code snippets) is 'Message dialog' or `JOptionPane` instead of `JFrame` as it might more commonly be displayed in. 3) What happened when you ran that code?  What did you expect to happen?  -- We need more information from you, if we are to help you solve whatever the problem is.

Comment: Thank you sir, it's working in fact my path was not correct