# JFileChooser image to buffered image

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser, javax.imageio

I am having some issues getting my programs to run. Basically step 1 of my program is to use the JFileChooser to open up an image and make it into a buffered image, simple enough right? this is what I have:

```
JButton open = new JButton();
            JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
            File selectedFile = fc.getSelectedFile();
            fc.setDialogTitle("Please choose an image...");
            FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("JPEG", "jpeg", "jpg", "png", "bmp", "gif");
            BufferedImage origImage = null;

            String path = "";
            File f = fc.getSelectedFile();
            boolean exists = false;
            fc.addChoosableFileFilter(filter);


            try {

                f = fc.getSelectedFile();
                exists = f.exists();
                path = f.getAbsolutePath();

                origImage = ImageIO.read(new File(path));
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
                System.exit(0);
            }
```

im getting a null pointer exception (caught by my catch statement) I think it has something to do with the getbsolutepath, but im not sure. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with `origImage = ImageIO.read(f);`?

Comment: You never seem to open the file chooser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never seem to actually open the file chooser, so no file is ever selected which would account for the `NullPointerException`

```
JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
fc.setDialogTitle("Please choose an image...");
FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("JPEG", "jpeg", "jpg", "png", "bmp", "gif");
fc.addChoosableFileFilter(filter);

BufferedImage origImage = null;
// You should use the parent component instead of null
// but it was impossible to tell from the code snippet what that was.
if (fc.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    File selectedFile = fc.getSelectedFile();
    try {
        origImage = ImageIO.read(selectedFile);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Take a look at [How to Use File Choosers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html) for more details

Comment: how would I go about making it terminate the program if the user hits cancel on the JFileChooser pane?

Comment: @Elchapo There's lots of ways you might be able to do it depending on your code, you could use a `else` statement to simple call `System.exit(0)`, but I always find that a bit harsh.  It might be better to check to see if `origImage` is `null` or not, if it is, you just let the execution fall through to the end of the method and if it's not `null`, you process it in what ever way you want

Comment: Thanks a bunch! the origImage == null makes sense! Thanks!!

Comment: And `new FileNameExtensionFilter("JPEG", "jpeg", "jpg", "png", "bmp", "gif");` would best be more like: `new FileNameExtensionFilter(
    "Image files", ImageIO.getReaderFileSuffixes());` See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13521592/418556) for more details.

Answer (score -2):

Try this

path = f.getAbsolutePath().replace("\", "\\");

Comment: It's not required, `ImageIO.read` can take a `File` reference, so the OP shoudln't be messing about with `String` file names anyway and since the OP never actual states them, there should be no reason to change then as the API will have already accounted for them