# How to set filter for file type in FileDialog

Tags: java, swing, filedialog

I need to add the type of JPG and PNG files in the File Dialog to be added to Files of type To allow the user to see only these two types of files this is my code after click on button in GUI form.

```
jLabel2.setText("");
Frame frame = null;
FileDialog fd = new FileDialog(frame, "Select Cover Photo");
fd.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
fd.setVisible(true);
if (fd.getFile() != null) {
    String path = new File(fd.getDirectory(), fd.getFile()).getAbsolutePath();
    if (new File(path).length() / 1024 > 1536) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "picture size can't mor than 1.5 MG");
    } 
    else {
        System.out.println(path);
        jLabel2.setText(path);
        fd.dispose();
        System.out.println("size= " + new File(path).length() / 1024 + " KB");
    }
} else {
    System.out.println("No Data");
    fd.dispose();
}
```

I have used this method to view photos before selecting. Please pay attention to the photo.

[image]

Comment: Use a **`JFileCooser`** as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13521592/418556).  Note that the AWT based `FileDialog`: 1) Is more limited, since it can offer only the functionality that can be guaranteed across all platforms. 2) Will look different on Unix / Linux and Mac OS. You won't be able to offer the 'Windows looking' file dialog on those platforms, and users would expect a different look in any case.

Comment: in JFileCooser  user can't see image before select

Comment: Be sure to read the edits to my comment before wasting more time on this..

Answer (score 1):

Basically all you need to do is put a filter to your `FileDialog`, You could do it this way:

```java
fd.setFilenameFilter( (dir, name) -> name.endsWith(".jpeg") || name.endsWith(".png") );
```

But I would recommend using `JFileChooser`, It has a lot more capabilities.
For example you can add several file filters this way:

```java
        FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
        fileChooser.setInitialFileName("Your File");

        fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().addAll(
                new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("Image 1", "*.jpg"),
                new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("Image 2", "*.png"),
        );
```

1. Link to API docs for the AWT based [`FileDialog`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/FileDialog.html).
2. Link to API docs for the Swing based [`JFileChooser`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html),
3. Link to API docs for the Java-FX based [`FileChooser`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/FileChooser.html).

It takes special handling to integrate Java-FX components into a Swing based app, as each uses different threads. So that has to be taken into consideration too.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I have to improve my answers by adding references, thank you.